# ADF's Azure Function component not working with Self-Hosted Integration Runtime

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

Good day All,

I have a running Self-Hosted IR on a on-Prem machine(with internet facing) and registered successfully on the Data Factory as a active node.

I manage to access on-Prem DB via 'Copy Data' component (Move data from onPrem DB to Azure DB) with the IR.

However, I am not able to access the on-Prem DB via 'Function App' component even if I have configured by Azure function app to connect with IR.

please advice if i have missed out anything..

[image]